# how to start storing Eclipse project to local svn repository? (fresh install of everything)

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn

I've just installed Ubuntu, Eclipse 4.4 Luna C/C++, everything with default settings. I've created my first c++ project and want to start storing entire Eclipse workspace in svn repository (also I expect Eclipse GUI to work with repository). SVN repository itself i want to store locally (likely in Dropbox folder).

What steps should I do?

**upd** That's how I solved my problem:

1. To install subversion in Ubuntu execute `sudo apt-get install subversion`
2. In Eclipse just go to Help-Install new software. Select "all available sites" and type "Subversive" install everything
3. After Eclipse restart install "SVNKit" connector of the same version as `svn --help`
4. In SVN Repository Exploring perspective just click "New Repository" and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store the entire workspace in SVN, just store the project.

Install SVN on a machine, pay attention to the svn admin tools.

```
svnadmin create /path/to/root/of/repo
```

Edit the /path/to/root/of/repo/config/svnserve.conf

1. Uncomment `anon-access = whatever` and change it to `anon-access = none`
2. Uncomment `auth-access = whatever` and change it to `auth-access = write`
3. Uncomment `password-db = passwd`

Edit the /path/to/root/of/repo/config/passwd

1. Add under the [users] section a line that looks like `yourUserName = yourPassword`

Find the instructions for your operating system to configure the program `svnserve` to run.

Now you should be able to checkout to other machines, you'll still need to "finish off" the respository you created.  It needs tags/trunk/branches.

```
svn checkout svn://hostname.of.server/repo
cd repo
mkdir trunk tags branches
svn add trunk tags branches
svn commit -m "Initial repository setup"
```

after you get the messages the commit succeeded

```
cd ..
rm -rf repo
svn co svn://hostname.of.server/repo/trunk repo

(and use that as the root of your Eclipse project directory)
```

I highly recommend doing the last checkout in the IDE, after adding in the SVN support bundles.

Comment: There are many ways to go about this, but this way is the easiest that actually will permit multiple users and be at least somewhat secure.

Comment: thanks, i was hoping i can do this in windows-style, just clicking and using IDE, not using command-line :)

Comment: You might be able to, but it gets harder that way.  Many IDEs have optimizations for the commands you typically call "checkout" "commit", etc.  Very few have the admin commands, and even then, they can't run them on a "possibly different" machine.  Read the "SVN Red Book" for the details of various kinds of setups, I've described the svnserve setup, which is pretty easy (but lacks some features).